# Rails, how can I make a synchronous serial queue than works in multi-thread/process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, ruby-on-rails-4, message-queue

In my Rails 4 with Ruby 2 app I've the following model:

[image: Playlist and Tracks model]

A `Playlist` can have many `Track`s and each `Track` has its `position` in its `Playlist`. For each new `Track` I want to set its `position` to be the last, in thread-safe and/or multi-process-safe way.

In my research I found a bunch of projects that handle background jobs but I don't want this to be background, I want it to be synchronous. So the caller of my API will get the response with the correct `position`.

The question is: what's the best way to make a synchronous serial queue that will be used to set the position of a `Track` in its `Playlist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be synchronous, then you don't need a queue.  Instead you'd just wrap a bit of code in a transaction where you find the last track position for that playlist, then set the position of the new track to be one more, then save the new track.  Something like this (assuming you're in a controller action):

```
@playlist = Playlist.find params[:id]
@track = Track.new params[:track]
@playlist.transaction do
  last_track = @playlist.tracks.order("posistion desc").first
  @track.position = last_track.position + 1
  @track.save
end
```

Comment: Would this work for a multi-process deploy? E.g. using Unicorn. Nonetheless, I think you're right about queues being the wrong solution for this problem.

Comment: Yes, this would be fine for a multi-process deploy.  You're relying on the database to insulate each process.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, if you want it to be a synchronous call just add it to your controller action.
Just have one question, is there a requirement that you explicitly require a position attribute in the Track model. Because by default the track that you add to the playlist is added to the end

```
playlist = Playlist.find params[:id]
playlist.transaction.do
  playlist.tracks.create(params[:track]) 
end
```

So when you want the last track that you added, then you can just fetch it by

```
playlist.tracks.last
```

If you want some kind of ordering for your tracks, then you can add some scope method to your Track model to render your tracks "by newest to oldest" or "by oldest to newest"(example without position attribute).

```
scope: sort_by_newest, order('created_at desc')
scope: sort_by_oldest, order('created_at asc')
```

If you still need an explicit tracking with the position attribute, then

```
playlist = Playlist.find params[:id]
track_params = params[:track] || {}
track_params.merge!({position: playlist.tracks.count('id') + 1})
playlist.transaction.do
  playlist.tracks.create(track_params) 
end
```

If you want some kind of ordering for your tracks, then you can add some scope method to your Track model to render your tracks "by newest to oldest" or "by oldest to newest"(example with position attribute).

```
scope: sort_by_newest, order('position desc')
scope: sort_by_oldest, order('position asc')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The suggestion that tracks are "automatically added to the end" is problematic.  This assumes that there has not been any sort of default order specified at the model level which means that the Rails default of ordering by `id asc` is still in force.  Even if the default ordering is still in place, this further breaks down if you're not using integer ids, if you're using UUIDs for example.  If order is important it's always best to be explicit about it.

Comment: Agreed. For ordering would recommend to use default_scope/named_scope in models.